# MERGE table, do nothing when matched

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, match, sql-merge

I have a table `DOMAINS` in 2 different schemas with columns `ID`, `NAME`,`CODE`,`DESCRIPTION`.

For any `NAME` exist in new schema, it should use existing `ID` without any merge; for those new `NAME` records, it should insert with `ID` from old schema.

```
MERGE INTO domains a
     USING ( SELECT id, name, code, description 
               FROM <Old Schema 6.1>.domains@db_mig_61_to_74 ) b
        ON ( a.name = b.name )
      WHEN MATCHED **<do nothing>**
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( a.id, a.name, a.code, a.description ) 
                            VALUES( b.id, b.name, b.code, b.description );
```

*How can i intepret the portion of `do nothing` in above query?*

Comment: This version of merge against snowflake is creating duplicates in snowflake and I think it's because of null values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your case, no need to use the part:

`WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...`

( *using `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.id = a.id` is accepted(Oracle doesn't hurl) but has no impact, so, such a usage is redundant, because you don't want to change anything for the matching case.* )

> If you wanted to change, then add
>
> `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.id = b.id`
>
> before `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT...`
>
> ( *e.g.Oracle supports `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`  syntax. Refer **the
> Demo** below* )

*Go on with the following for the current case :*

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE domains( 
                           id          INT, 
                           name        VARCHAR2(50), 
                           code        VARCHAR2(50), 
                           description VARCHAR2(50)
                         );

SQL> INSERT INTO domains VALUES(1,'Domain A','D.A.','This is Domain A');

SQL> MERGE INTO domains a USING 
     (SELECT 2 id, 'Domain A' name, 'D.A.' code, 'This is Domain A' description 
        FROM domains) b
          ON ( a.name = b.name )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( a.id, a.name, a.code, a.description ) 
                              VALUES( b.id, b.name, b.code, b.description );

SQL> SELECT * FROM domains;

ID  NAME        CODE    DESCRIPTION
--  --------   -----  ----------------
1   Domain A    D.A.  This is Domain A

SQL> DELETE domains;

SQL> INSERT INTO domains VALUES(1,'Domain A','D.A.','This is Domain A');
-- we're deleting and inserting the same row again

SQL> MERGE INTO domains a USING       
 (SELECT 2 id, 'Domain B' name, 'D.B.' code, 'This is Domain B' description 
    FROM domains) b
      ON ( a.name = b.name )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( a.id, a.name, a.code, a.description ) 
                          VALUES( b.id, b.name, b.code, b.description );


SQL> SELECT * FROM domains;

ID  NAME        CODE    DESCRIPTION
--  --------   -----  ----------------
1   Domain A    D.A.  This is Domain A
2   Domain B    D.B.  This is Domain B
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rvGWTblX)</kbd>

**Btw**, the part followed by the `USING` keyword no need to be a ***subquery***, but a ***table*** or a ***view***. Having evaluated for the current case:

```
MERGE INTO domains ds       --> "ds" : "domains" source
     USING v_domains dt     --> "dt" : "domains" target
        ON ( ds.name = dt.name )
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( ds.id, ds.name, ds.code, ds.description ) 
                            VALUES( dt.id, dt.name, dt.code, dt.description )
```

might identically be used like the above statement after having created **`v_domains`** view through

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_domains AS
SELECT 2 id, 'Domain A' name, 'D.A.' code, 'This is Domain A' description 
  FROM domains
```

Answer (score 10):

Oracle SQL syntax supports not having any `when matched then update` clause.

```
drop table ft purge;
create table ft (c1 number, c2 varchar2(10));

drop table ld purge;
create table ld (c1 number, c2 varchar2(10));

insert into ft values (1,'a');
insert into ld values (1,'b');
insert into ld values (2,'c');
commit;

merge into ft 
using ld
on (ft.c1 = ld.c1) 
when not matched then
insert (c1,c2) values (ld.c1,ld.c2);

select * from ft;

C1  C2
--- ---
1   a
2   c

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: This works better than the chosen solution when you have a column that shows when the row was last updated that you don't want to change when there's a match.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: That wasn't in doubt.  The answer is saying that a merge statement is valid SQL even if it doesn't have a "when matched" clause.  "Supports not having" is very different from "does not support having".

Comment: exactly @BenVoigt thanks, I really had misunderstood then :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use
merge into A
using B
on ...
when not matched then
...

which I've verified is valid ...