# SQL MERGE: Is it possible to ignore a MATCH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2017

Here's my merge statement:

```
MERGE PE_TranslationPhrase T
USING PE_TranslationPhrase_Staging S 
ON (T.CultureName = S.CultureName AND T.Phrase = S.Phrase)
WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE SET T.TranslationId = T.TranslationId -- do nothing
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (TranslationId, CultureName, Phrase)
        VALUES (S.TranslationId, S.CultureName, S.Phrase);
```

I seem to be having trouble with the `WHEN MATCHED` section.  Based [on this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848995/merge-table-do-nothing-when-matched), I changed the `WHEN MATCHED` to:

```
THEN UPDATE SET T.TranslationId = T.TranslationId
```

But I am still getting this error:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

I get the reason why.  Based on the `ON` statement, I am getting duplicate matches. But... I don't care.  If a record from the source table already exists in the target table, then I want to just do nothing.  Don't update anything at all.  Skip it.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just omit the `WHEN MATCHED` section?

Comment: Worth mentioning you can't match on NULL so you should ideall have ISNULLs around your two matching columns (if they aren't already NOT NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no update is being done, have you considered just doing the insert using rows from `PE_TranslationPhrase_Staging` that aren't in `PE_TranslationPhrase`?

**CTE Approach:**

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    S.TranslationId, 
    S.CultureName, 
    S.Phrase
FROM PE_TranslationPhrase_Staging S 
LEFT JOIN PE_TranslationPhrase T on S.Phrase = T.Phrase and S.CultureName = T.CultureName
WHERE T.PHRASE IS NULL
)

INSERT INTO PE_TranslationPhrase (TranslationId, CultureName, Phrase)
SELECT 
    TranslationId, 
    CultureName, 
    Phrase
FROM CTE
```

**Subquery Approach:**

```
INSERT INTO PE_TranslationPhrase (TranslationId, CultureName, Phrase)
SELECT 
TW.TranslationId, 
TW.CultureName, 
TW.Phrase
FROM (
SELECT 
    S.TranslationId, 
    S.CultureName, 
    S.Phrase
FROM PE_TranslationPhrase_Staging S 
LEFT JOIN PE_TranslationPhrase T on S.Phrase = T.Phrase and S.CultureName = T.CultureName
WHERE T.PHRASE IS NULL ) TW
```

Comment: What would the speed/cost be with this compared to a merge?

Comment: There are multiple issues with the merge, some of which relate to deadlocking which may not be a problem anyhow since only an insert is done.  The following link further outlines these.  As far as the performance I'd recommend running a test for both, then looking at the Execution Plan to see what logical/physical operators, indexes, etc., were utilized and in what way.  A subquery would actually possibly perform better, I just used a CTE for clarity here.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: I'm sure you're familiar with subqueries, but I updated my post with an example of this.  Also note that a subquery must be aliased (TW above)

Answer (score 10):

Oh.  Turns out you don't need the 'WHEN MATCHED' statement.  I thought it was required.

```
MERGE PE_TranslationPhrase T
USING PE_TranslationPhrase_Staging S 
ON (T.CultureName = S.CultureName AND T.Phrase = S.Phrase)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (TranslationId, CultureName, Phrase)
        VALUES (S.TranslationId, S.CultureName, S.Phrase);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that you cannot match on NULL so I would use ISNULL around both match columns to ensure you don't get "Not matched" when both tables have a NULL value in the match column

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what can not be done in the MERGE statement to omit this error. But I have solved this by generating an identity column (NOT persistent) that allows me to add a unique value to each record for both the `source` and `target` of the sentence and compare the form. Something like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CultureName, Phrase ORDER BY CultureName, Phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `Merge ... When Matched ...` in such cases that there are multiple matches and as you could find out, you can simply remove the `When Matched` section.   However if you needed this section for `update`, instead of using `Merge` you can use the following code:

```
update PE_TranslationPhrase
set  TranslationId = S.xxx
from
PE_TranslationPhrase T, PE_TranslationPhrase_Staging S
where T.CultureName = S.CultureName AND T.Phrase = S.Phrase
```